# chrome dev tools copy as curl - doesn't copy HTTP method

Tags: curl, google-chrome-devtools

In the network tab - > filter by XHR requests, when I copy a HTTP request  with ' copy as curl. It doesn't appear to copy the HTTP method.  However this doesn't seem to cause a problem when testing an external api. (verified on GET and POST requests as specified in chrome).
I'm not that familar with curl, but does anyone else see the same lack of HTTP method when copying?

eg:

```
$ curl 'https://api.somedomain.com' -H 'origin: https://www.somedomain.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://www.somedomain.com/path/path2' -H 'authority: api.theenergyshop.co.uk' --data-binary '{'somepayload: 'test'}' --compressed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `X` flag specifies HTTP method. If it's omitted, cURL defaults to `GET`. DevTools is properly setting the flag for the request in this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/lepomo/edit?html,js,console,output). At least on OS X, Version 51.0.2681.0 canary (64-bit).

`curl 'https://httpbin.org/post' -X POST -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'origin: http://null.jsbin.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'referer: http://null.jsbin.com/runner' -H 'content-length: 0' --compressed`

Comment: thanks, it isn't setting the method on the test I did, but now I can't seem to reproduce the issue.  Thanks for confirming that it does copy the method too.